# Purpose of alias attribute in A tags? Is it an ExactTarget feature?

Tags: html, alias

I'm working with someone else's html file, which is to be sent as an email through a web software known as Exact Target.  In the html template, I see `<a alias=":Logo_hello_world">`.  This is the first time I've seen the alias attribute used in HTML mark up.   What are alias attributes used for?  Is it something specific to Exact Target?  I tried to google the subject matter, but the alias attribute doesn't seem to be a popular attribute.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The alias tag in Exact Target can be set on links to track response to specific link in the cases where single urls is used multiple times (typically different areas) of the email.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to keep each alias tag unique.  If you use the same alias tag on all links, it will only show up once in the reporting.

Answer (score 0):

When multiple links in an email points to same URl, then to track in reporting we use HTML  tag with alias to identify which locations link was clicked or opened.